# Excel VBA - Summing figures that are in black coloured font with multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I'm having problems summing figures that are in black font. This is because I only need the Amt figures(in columns D,I,N,S) as shown in this [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/276i1.png)

This is the VBA Code I've found after searching online [VBA Code Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL7do.png)

Here is the VBA Code itself:

```
Function SumByColor(rng As Range, FntClr As Range) As Double
Dim c As Range, TempSum As Double
Application.Volatile
clr = FntClr.Font.Color
TempSum = 0
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If c.Font.Color = clr Then
        TempSum = TempSum + c.Value
    End If
Next c
On Error GoTo 0
Set c = Nothing
SumByColor = TempSum
End Function
```

Right now because there is a C/S # which is a number itself, the current VBA Code i use will sum the C/S# (Black in font colour) itself into the Outstanding Amount which should not be the case.

Any idea how should do I select the column cells I need only? I have a feeling that `=SumByColor(A1:S3,T7)` is the code i have to change but how do I change it to only summing the columns in Column D,I,N,S?

BTW, Red Font = Payment made, Black Font = Outstanding Payment

Comment: Images of code are absolutely useless to us. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should avoid them. Code is text, and should be posted as such, where it can be properly formatted.

Comment: have a close look at the code. then do web search on how to work with ranges in excel VBA

Comment: Noted. Have updated the code in OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the header for each column in the input range:

```
Function SumByColor(rng As Range, FntClr As Range) As Double
    Const HDR As String = "AMT"
    Dim c As Range, TempSum As Double, clr As Long, col As Range
    Application.Volatile
    clr = FntClr.Font.Color
    TempSum = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    'check each column in the input range
    For Each col In rng.Columns
        'Only check cells where the header is "AMT"
        If col.EntireColumn.Cells(1).Value = HDR Then
            For Each c In col.Cells
                If c.Font.Color = clr Then
                    TempSum = TempSum + c.Value
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next col
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set c = Nothing
    SumByColor = TempSum
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

The way to only select the columns D,I,N,S out of the range A1:S3 is:

```
Intersect([A1:S3],[D:D,I:I,N:N,S:S])
```

---

If columns D,I,N,S are fixed, you should do this inside your vba function.

Otherwise, you might have to add an extra parameter to your function ...